# set value of input element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, steroids

I am trying to change the value of the inputfields with JQuery and I have no idea why this doesn't work. It does not throw an error but it just doesn't change. I'm building with appgyver steroids but i don't think that matters.

javascript:

```
$(document.getElementById("url")).val('test');
```

html

```
 <input type="text" id="url" class="topcoat-text-input"
       style="margin-left:10%; margin-top:10px; width: 80%; text-align: center" autocapitalize="off"
       autocorrect="off" required="true"
       placeholder="something else"/>
```

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/McTY3/

Comment: `$(document.getElementById("url")).val('test');` is excessive. if you want a jquery object use `$("#url")`. If you just want to change the value just use `document.getElementById("url").value = "test"`.

Comment: What point in the page load/user interfacing is this supposed to happen?  Are you trying to have it change when an event occurs or just at the beginning of page load (...also an event lol)

Comment: My guess (and It is a good one) is that you are loading the HTML in after you have loaded the page (ajax?) and therefore the js is not going to do anything.

Comment: The html is in the page. its the very first file that is being loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your code is running after the DOM is loaded.

Also there is no need for jQuery in your example.

You can just do:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("url").value = 'test';
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/7uCfc/

---

And if you want to do full on jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#url').val('test');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/m5Ttn/

---

Or you *could* **not** wrap your code in an `onload` and just put the whole script at the end of the document after the page has loaded already.

Comment: neither change anything.

Comment: It should have. See the Demos. Can you **show** what you tried please @DaanLuttik ?